# Unsure if Sort-Object works like I think it works

Tags: powershell

I have a Variable called `$CompleteDataSetOldDb` with 26805 `PSCustomObject` in it. The Objects all look like this (all have the same PropertyNames):

```
Klasse         : TbAEinschubelementHalter
NeueKlasse     : EinschubelementHalter
ArtikelNr      : 12.Z36D0080.12
NameDE         : Halteteil Höhe D, weiss Set für Einschubelemente
NameFR         : adaptateur hauteur D, blanc Set pour inserts
Parameter      : FarbeZarge
ParameterValue : Stahl Weiss
ItemGroupID    : 12
```

Now I know that I also have duplicates in this Variable. I'd like to get rid of them. With duplicates I mean that they have the exaxt same `ArtikelNr`, `Parameter` and `ParameterValue` combination. The combination of these 3 properties can only be in my Variable once.

Here you can see one entry that is exactly the same:

```
Klasse         : TbXOrgalineQuerteilerAufnahme
NeueKlasse     : OrgalineQuerteilerAufnahme
ArtikelNr      : 12.Z40C0002Z.12
NameDE         : Querteileraufnahme C weiss zu Profil Z40L1077
NameFR         : Support séparateur, blanc pour Profil Z40L1077
Parameter      : FarbeZarge
ParameterValue : Stahl weiss
ItemGroupID    : 31


Klasse         : TbXOrgalineQuerteilerAufnahme
NeueKlasse     : OrgalineQuerteilerAufnahme
ArtikelNr      : 12.Z40C0002Z.12
NameDE         : Querteileraufnahme C weiss zu Profil Z40L1077
NameFR         : Support séparateur, blanc pour Profil Z40L1077
Parameter      : FarbeZarge
ParameterValue : Stahl weiss
ItemGroupID    : 31
```

They both have `ArtikelNr 12.Z40C0002Z.12`, `Parameter FarbeZarge` and `ParameterValue Stahl weiss` so I only need it in my Variable once.

I tried to filter them simply like this:

```
$CompleteDataSetOldDB | Sort-Object ArtikelNr, Parameter, ParameterValue -Unique
```

And from my 26805 objects, only 15067 still remain.

Did my `Sort-Object` work like I intended, namely filtered out all duplicates of objects that have the same combination of the 3 propertys? Is there a Command I can run to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it works like you think. It's easy enough to test using a contrived subset of your data, isn't it?

In reality, if you have a reason not to trust `Sort-Object`, then you should verify it manually. If you don't trust `Sort-Object`, I don't understand why you would trust another Powershell command at all. They may use the same logic or miss the same corner cases (like leading or trailing whitespace, not slugging non-breaking spaces, etc.).

If I were going to verify it manually, I would start with `Group-Object`.

```
$CompleteDataSetOldDB | Sort-Object -Property ArtikelNr, Parameter, ParameterValue |
    Group-Object -Property ArtikelNr, Parameter, ParameterValue -NoElement
```

That should return each unique group and the number of elements in each group. You may want to pipe the output to `Format-Table -Autosize` or `Export-Csv` to see everything.

Alternately, you could do this:

```
$CompleteDataSetOldDB | Sort-Object -Property ArtikelNr, Parameter, ParameterValue -Unique |
    Export-Csv Unique.csv -NoTypeInformation

$CompleteDataSetOldDB | Sort-Object -Property ArtikelNr, Parameter, ParameterValue |
    Export-Csv Duplicated.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Then open `Duplicated.csv` with a text editor that has a function which can eliminate duplicate rows. Eliminate the duplicate rows, then compare the de-duplicated `Duplicated.csv` with `Unique.csv` using WinMerge or similar.

If I was still not convinced, then I would import my entire data set into an SQL RDBMS and then execute:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ArtikelNr, Parameter, ParameterValue
FROM StagingTable
```

Note that I don't recommend using Excel for this because it silently alters data.

Comment: You know, even though I use it for 5 years now, sometimes I just can't believe that PowerShell is really that easy. They did really good work creating it. Thanks for confirming my command!

Comment: @SimonS Yup! The only thing I could imagine happening to trip up the sorting and unique-ness algorithm would be based on the data and the data types. If a custom data type doesn't have a proper `Equals()` or `CompareTo()` method, or if you want byte-wise instead of culture-based sorting, or if there are decomposed characters in one record and precomposed characters in another which represent the same glyph (some diacritics can do that), or other culture-based sorting issues. But many sorting algorithms would get tripped up by that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer *complements* [Bacon Bits' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895186/45375), which solves your problem.

There is a **caveat** with respect to **`Sort-Object -Unique` in combination with `-Property`** (property-based sort criteria):

**`-Unique` only applies to the *sort criteria values***, and not to the objects *as a whole*.

That is, **if the properties *not* being sorted by *differ* among objects that share the same sort-criteria property values, you will *lose information***, as only *one* among those objects will be output, and *which one* isn't predictable.

(This doesn't seem to apply in your case, but it's worth pointing out in general.)

For example:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ one=1; other='A' }, [pscustomobject] @{ one=1; other='B' } |
      Sort-Object one -Unique

one other
--- -----
 10 A        # !! Only 1 object is output among all where .one equals 1
```

To prevent that, [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) must be used, which has the same syntax for sort criteria and allows examining *all* objects that share sort-criteria (grouping-criteria) values via the output objects' `.Group` property.

---

On a somewhat related note:

For the purposes of **uniqueness detection** (and also sorting, though it doesn't make sense to sort `[pscustomobject]` instances *as a whole*), **PowerShell considers all `[pscustomobject]` instances to be *the same* even if they have completely unrelated properties (and/or values)**:

For example:

```
# Note the different property names (and values).
PS> [pscustomobject] @{foo='A'}, [pscustomobject] @{bar='B'}, [pscustomobject] @{baz='C'} |
      Select-Object -Unique

foo
---
A     # !! Only the *first* object is output, because all are considered the same.
```